# why after click on tag <a>, page refresh and not work appendTo?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

tag *a* is to $.each(). see my js code:

```
 $('.auto_complete').keyup(function () {
                var id = '#' + this.id;
                var alt = $(id).attr('alt'); var id = $(this).attr('id'); var name = $(this).attr('name');
                var url = alt + id + '/' + name;
            var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: dataObj,
                cache: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $(".list_name").show().html('');            
                    $.each(data.name, function(a,b){
                        $(".list_name").append('<p><a href="" id="result">' + b + '</a></p>');
    ////////////////////here/////////////////////
                        $('.list_name p a').live('click', function(e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $('<b>' + b + '، </b><input type="text" name="hotel[]" value="' + b + '" style="border: none; display: none;" />').appendTo('.auto_box span');
                                    $(this).remove();
                                return false;
                                });
    /////////////////////////////////////////////
                    });
                    if($('.auto_complete').val()==''){
                        $(".list_name p").hide().remove()
                    }
                    $('body').click(function(){
                            $(".list_name p").hide().remove();
                            $('.auto_complete').val('');
                        });
                },
                "error": function (x, y, z) {
                    // callback to run if an error occurs
                    alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
                }
                });

            });
```

php:(i use of codeigniter)

```
function search_hotel(){
            $search_term = $this->input->post('search_hotel');
            $query = $this->db->order_by("id", "desc")->like('name', $search_term)->get('hotel_submits');
            $data = array();
            foreach ($query->result() as $row)
            {
               $data[] = $row->name;
            }
            echo json_encode(array('name' => $data));
    // echo: {"name":["333333","\u0633\u0644","\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0633\u06cc","\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0633\u0633","\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645"]}
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what you expect to happen, and what incorrect behavior you have observed?

Comment: I added more info and questions in my answer

Answer (score 2):

How you approach the solution might depend on whatever else you have attached to your link in terms of events. I would try it like this instead:

```
$('.list_name p a').live('click', function() {
    $('<b>' + b + '، </b><input type="text" name="hotel[]" value="' + b + '" />').appendTo('.auto_box span');
    $('.list_name p a').remove();
    return false;
});
```

I created a [jsFiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZnExJ/), which seems to be working just fine. If you're still getting a form submission then there might be other syntax errors in your code or other events tied to your elements that are interfering or preventing the desired behavior from occurring.

Comment: after click on '.list_name p a' page refresh?

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` is enough to stop the default behavior. Also `return false` works but it will stop event bubbling, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: What is `b` and when does it get set? You might a run time error that is causing the trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Because the event was not attached. Why? You must debug it... do you have errors in your browser Javascript console? Maybe stopped parsing due of some error.

Maybe you are not selecting the right a element (list_name or list-name)... etc.

UPDATE
What version of jQuery are you using?
You can place the binding of the event outside of the AJAX call to test. It should work that way too.
You can try also to attach it to the parent .list_name  , the events bubble up, so it's more efficient doing it like this.
Are you having any errors in the console log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.list_name p a').live('click', function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
```

var b = "defineIt";
                                $('**' + b + '،** ').appendTo('.auto_box span');
                                $(this).remove();
    return false;
                            });

Comment: The problem not was solved. Is still Refresh page. what do i do?

Comment: I see the problem where it is. Where is b defined? It is throwing a js error because b id undefined due to which it is refreshing the page. Define b = something in the function and try. I have edited my answer take a look.

Comment: b is defined here `$.each(data.name, function(a,b)` See the documentation of $.each